# testing - how to test submit function without hit the api?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm now learning to test react with jest and enzyme. I'm facing a problem when I want to disable button upon submit, but in the function, I don't want to hit an API. how can I do that?

**App.js**

```js
function Login() {
  const [isSubmitting, setIsSubmitting] = useState(false)

  const submitLogin = () => {
    setIsSubmitting(true);

    axios.get('http://.....')
  }

  return (
    <div>
      // I want to check if button disabled, but I don't want to really hit the API in submitLogin
      <Button disabled={isSubmitting} data-testid="submit_button" onClick={submitLogin}>Login</Button>
      // ....
    </div>
  )
}
```

my **App.test.js**, it actually made the button disabled, but the API also hit

```js
test('should disable button upon submit', () => {
  const button = wrapper.find('[data-testid="submit_button"]')
  button.props().onClick();
  expect(button.props().disabled).toBe(true)
})
```

how can I achieve my aim? I read that we can create mock function, but I don't know if it can change hook state. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `axios-mock-adapter`;
2. 

```
import axios from 'axios';

jest.mock('axios');

const mockData = 'mock';

axios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(mockData));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can mock the axios import

```
jest.mock('axios', () => {
    return {
      get: jest.fn(),
    }
})
```